# Error importing tensorflow in anaconda on Mac OSX

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am trying to import tensorflow using python and anaconda on Mac OSX 10.11.6 (El Capitan). I have followed the instructions on tensorflow.org relating to installation with anaconda as follows:

```
conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.6
source activate tensorflow
sudo -H pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.10.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

And then starting python, and typing import tensorflow, produces an error:

`ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation`

Followed by more similar errors which resulted in a failure to load the native tensorflow runtime.

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: why don't you just do `sudo pip3 install tensorflow` instead, it would automatically download the latest version for you. Or you could even specify the version.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that as well, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: what's the error you got after that?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error message while installing TensorFlow.  I was also using OSX 10.11.6.  I got past that step by upgrading OSX.  I was tipped off that this was necessary because a few lines farther down on the error message that you posted (after the dlopen part), it mentioned that the libraries had been compiled for a later version of OSX (10.12).  When I upgraded to OSX 10.13, that error message went away.

If you're getting the same error in your error message, this will probably get you past that part.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I upgraded my operating system to OSX High Sierra, and then the installation was successful.

Answer (score 0):

If someone gets here and has, for some reason, to run TensorFlow on OSX 10.11 El Capitan, the latest version supported is `tensorflow==1.9.0`.